# Random Falling Objects from Screen in Android

Tags: android

I haven't tried anything yet. But I'm thinking of using `TranslateAnimation` to move the objects from top to bottom. Basically, I have to accomplish like what you see in the image below:

[image]

What is the most easy and pratical way of doing this? Would it be better to use OpenGL? Or do I have to stick with basic animations? I haven't had any experience on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things, beginning position and end position. Your beginning position will be the top and end position will be the bottom.

Since you want a random effect, simply calculate a random number from 0 to [screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and set that number as the `x` position of your element. Do this for all of your elements.

To animate, you can use any type of animation that is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html).

You'll probably also want to offset or delay each animation from each other so that they all don't animate down/up at the same time. This offset time can be fixed or random, up to you.